How to fix overlapping bins in log scale hexplot
I replicated the code given in the description of this image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Zipf%27s_law_on_War_and_Peace.png
It works for the predetermined figure size of (20, 24), but I would like to adapt it to fit my thesis page width. The new figure size then should be (5.9055, 7.0866), but just changing the figure size creates a mess of overlapping bins. Why does this happen?
Correct image with figsize (20, 24)

The image with overlapping bins with figsize (5.9055, 7.0866).
If you look at the lower plot, bins are scrambled and overlap each other.

You can use the following code to replicate the images:
from typing import Tuple
import nltk
import urllib.request
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import re
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_zipf(text: str, title, alpha=1, cmap='inferno', include_counts: bool = False, figsize: Tuple[float, float]=(20, 24)):
    tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer('\w+')
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower())
    # tokens = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), text.split()))

    # Randomly split the tokens into two corpora
    random.shuffle(tokens)
    half = len(tokens) // 2
    corpus1, corpus2 = tokens[:half], tokens[half:]

    # Count word frequencies in each corpus
    counter1 = Counter(corpus1)
    counter2 = Counter(corpus2)

    # Find common words in both corpora
    common_words = set(counter1.keys()) & set(counter2.keys())

    # Create a dictionary of word, frequency pairs where frequency is the average of frequencies in two corpora 
    freqs = {word: (counter1[word] + counter2[word]) / 2 for word in common_words}

    # Create a dictionary of word, rank pairs where rank is determined from the frequencies in the second corpus
    ranks = {word: rank
             for rank, (word, freq) in enumerate(
                sorted([(w, counter2[w]) for w in common_words], key=lambda x: -x[1]),
                1)
             }

    # Create arrays for ranks and frequencies, ordered by rank
    words = sorted(freqs.keys(), key=ranks.get)
    ranks = np.array([ranks[word] for word in words])
    counts = np.array([freqs[word] for word in words])

    # plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 30})
    fig = plt.figure(layout='constrained', figsize=figsize)
    axes = fig.subplot_mosaic('A;B', sharex=True)

    # Plot A: Zipf's Law with fitted line
    ax = axes['A']
    ax.set_title(f"Zipf's Law on {title}")
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')

    # Zipf law fit 
    indices = (ranks >= 10) & (ranks <= 1000)
    slope, intercept = np.polyfit(np.log(ranks[indices]), np.log(counts[indices]), 1)
    ax.plot(
        ranks,
        np.exp(intercept) * ranks ** slope,
        color='red',
        alpha=1,
        label=f"Zipf law ($f = 1/(r+{alpha})^{-slope:.2f}$)"
    )

    # Create the hexagonal heatmap using hexbin, on the log scale data 
    hb = ax.hexbin(
        ranks+alpha,
        counts,
        gridsize=100,
        cmap=cmap,
        bins='log',
        xscale='log',
        yscale='log',
    ) 
    if include_counts:
        cb = plt.colorbar(hb, ax=ax)
        cb.set_label('Counts in log10(N)')
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
    
    # Plot B: Zipf's Law with Zipf removed 
    ax = axes['B'] 
    ax.set_title('with Zipf removed')
    ax.set_xlabel('Frequency rank')
    ax.set_ylabel('Frequency/Zipf law')
    
    # Create the hexagonal heatmap using hexbin, on the log scale data
    hb = ax.hexbin(
        ranks+alpha,
        counts / (np.exp(intercept) * (ranks+alpha) ** slope),
        gridsize=100,
        cmap=cmap,
        bins='log',
        xscale='log',
        yscale='log',
    ) 
    if include_counts:
        cb = plt.colorbar(hb, ax=ax)
        cb.set_label('Counts in log10(N)')
    # ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
    # plt.show()
    return fig


def gutenberg(txt_url, title, alpha=1, figsize: Tuple[float, float]=(20, 24)): 
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(txt_url)
    print('response received')
    long_txt = response.read().decode('utf8') # Remove the Project Gutenberg boilerplate

    pattern = r'\*\*\* START OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK [^\*]* \*\*\*'
    match = re.search(pattern, long_txt)

    if match:
        start_index = match.end()
        end_marker = '*** END OF THE PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK'
        end_index = long_txt.find(end_marker, start_index)
        long_txt = long_txt[start_index:end_index].strip()
    else:
        print('Pattern not found in the text.') # Tokenize the text

    return plot_zipf(long_txt, title, alpha=alpha, figsize=figsize)


# works fine here
gutenberg(
    'https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt', 
    'War and Peace', 
    alpha=2, 
    figsize=(20, 24),
)

# overlapping bins here
gutenberg(
    'https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2600/pg2600.txt', 
    'War and Peace', 
    alpha=2, 
    figsize=(5.9055, 7.0866),
)


Is the image the broken or the correct image, or an illustration of correct vs broken?

@tripleee the original image was the broken one. I added a correct version and titles, so it's clear. You might need to zoom in on the broken image to see whats going on. But when I save it as pdf it's very clear that something isn't right

Could you perhaps still [edit] to highlight what exactly to look for, where?

I guess the "real" issue is that your top 20x24 image has tiny text, so it becomes (even more) unreadable when downscaled. But, that's because 1) you commented out plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 30}) and 2) this appears to be jupyter notebook output since you replaced plt.show() with return fig. The text does indeed look tiny in the inline notebook output, but if you save with plt.savefig("zipf_war_peace.png") (or run the plt.show() version from the command line), the text is readable at 20x24 and should be able to be downscaled just fine.

@tdy thanks for the suggestions. In reality I am also changing the text, but only changing the figure size results in the scramble. For the figure size, I followed this blog: https://jwalton.info/Embed-Publication-Matplotlib-Latex/ The idea is to predetermine the size of the image so that the text in the image fits the text of the thesis
